# What are "Events" in hs_err_pid.log?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, java-threads

I've found these in my hs_err_pid.log.

```
Events (10 events):
Event: 2603309.010 Thread 0x00007ff2c800c000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007ff34aaddf69 sp=0x00007ff3409e88a8 mode 2
Event: 2603310.108 Thread 0x00007ff362229000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00007ff34b25ce6c sp=0x00007ff340ceb660
Event: 2603310.122 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00007ff34b890e40
Event: 2603310.124 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00007ff34b890e40 sp=0x00007ff3408e7790
Event: 2603310.124 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007ff34aaddf69 sp=0x00007ff3408e7680 mode 2
Event: 2603310.125 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00007ff34b850fe4
Event: 2603310.125 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00007ff34b850fe4 sp=0x00007ff3408e7560
Event: 2603310.125 Thread 0x00007ff2c8009800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007ff34aaddf69 sp=0x00007ff3408e72d8 mode 2
Event: 2603310.126 Thread 0x00007ff362229000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007ff34aaddf69 sp=0x00007ff340ceb628 mode 2
Event: 2603310.935 Thread 0x00007ff2d8001000 Thread added: 0x00007ff2d8001000
```

And I have no idea about these infomations and I'am curious even though it may not help me analyze the crash.

1. What does the number like "2603309.010" mean ?
2. What does the descriptions mean ? including DEOPT, UNPACKING/PACKING, Uncommon trap, trap_request, pc and sp ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a history of last 10 VM runtime events (other than compilation and GC).

`2603309.010` is a timestamp - number of seconds since VM start.

`Uncommon trap` is a situation when a speculative precondition in the compiled code fails. It usually results in `deoptimization` - switching from compiled code back to interpreter. Deoptimization first collects the information about virtual frames (packing) and then unrolls these frames onto the stack in the interpreter format (unpacking). `pc` and `sp` are program counter and stack pointer.

From [HotSpot Glossary of Terms](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html):

> **uncommon trap**
>
> When code generated by C2 reverts back to the
>   interpreter for further execution. C2 typically compiles for the
>   common case, allowing it to focus on optimization of frequently
>   executed paths. For example, C2 inserts an uncommon trap in generated
>   code when a class that is uninitialized at compile time requires run
>   time initialization.
>
> **deoptimization**
>
> The process of converting an compiled (or more
>   optimized) stack frame into an interpreted (or less optimized) stack
>   frame. Also describes the discarding of an nmethod whose dependencies
>   (or other assumptions) have been broken. Deoptimized nmethods are
>   typically recompiled to adapt to changing application behavior.
>   Example: A compiler initially assumes a reference value is never null,
>   and tests for it using a trapping memory access. Later on, the
>   application uses null values, and the method is deoptimized and
>   recompiled to use an explicit test-and-branch idiom to detect such
>   nulls.