# When busy-spining Java thread is bound to physical core, can context switch happen by the reason that new branch in code is reached?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jvm, low-latency

I am interested in low-latency code and that`s why I tried to configure thread affinity. In particular, it was supposed to help to avoid context switches.

I have configured thread affinity using https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity. I run very simple test code that just spins in a cycle checking a time condition.

```
    long now = start;
    while (true)
    {
        if (now < start + TimeUtils.NANOS_IN_SECOND * delay)
        {
            now = TimeUtils.now();
        }
        else
        {
            // Will be printed after 30 sec
            if (TimeUtils.now() > start + TimeUtils.NANOS_IN_SECOND * (delay + 30))
            {
                final long finalNow = now;
                System.out.println("Time is over at " +
                        TimeUtils.toInstant(finalNow) + " now: " +
                        TimeUtils.toInstant(TimeUtils.now()));
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, after the specified delay execution goes to "else" and approximately at the same time I see context switch. Is it an expected behavior? What is the specific reason for this? How can I avoid context switches in such cases?

**Test Details**

I build shadowJar from this repo: https://github.com/stepan2271/thread-affinity-example. Then I run it using the following command (one can play around with numbers here, it doesn`t have significant effect on test when delay > 60):

```
taskset -c 19 java -DtestLoopBindingCpu=3 -Ddelay=74 -cp demo-all.jar main.TestLoop
```

I also have the following test script to monitor context switches (should be run with ID of the Java thread that is bound to core)

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
date >> ~/demo-ctxt-switches.log
cat /proc/$1/status | grep ctxt >> ~/demo-ctxt-switches.log
sleep 3
done
```

Typical output of this script is the following:

```
Fri Oct 16 18:23:29 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    90
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:32 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    90
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:35 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    90
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:38 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    90
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:41 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    91
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:44 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    91
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
Fri Oct 16 18:23:47 MSK 2020
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    91
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 37
```

So, after some changes in start time these numbers become stable and then I see from 1 to 3 switches exactly (difference is less than 1 sec) at the time when code reaches "else" branch.

**Deviations**

Base configuration reproduces this behavior almost each time, while some deviations lead to situation when I didn`t manage to reproduce. Examples:

https://github.com/stepan2271/thread-affinity-example/tree/without-log4j

https://github.com/stepan2271/thread-affinity-example/tree/without-cached-nano-clock

**Test environment**

2 * Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6244 CPU @ 3.60GHz

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 (Ootpa)

Cores are isolated using CPUAffinity in /etc/systemd/system.conf and /etc/systemd/user.conf

/etc/sysconfig/irqbalance is configured.

Openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS Runtime Environment 18.9

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A voluntary context switch usually means a thread is waiting for something, e.g. for a lock to become free.

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) can help to find where context switches happen. Here is a command line I used:

```
./profiler.sh -d 80 -e context-switches -i 2 -t -f switches.svg -I 'main*' -X 'exit_to_usermode_loop*' PID
```

Let's go through it in detail:

- `-d 80` run profiler for at most 80 seconds.
- `-e context-switches` an event to profile.
- `-i 2` interval = 2 events. I profile every second context-switch, since the profiling signal itself causes a context switch, and I don't want to fall into recursion.
- `-t` split the profile by threads.
- `-f switches.svg` output file name; svg extension automatically selects Flame Graph format.
- `-I 'main*'` include only the main thread in the output.
- `-X 'exit_to_usermode_loop*'` exclude events related to nonvoluntary context switches.
- `PID` Java process ID to profile.

The results may differ from one run to another. Typically I see from 0 to 3 context switches on each graph.

[image: Context switches 1]

[image: Context switches 2]

Here are the most common places where a context switch happens. They are indeed related to waiting on a mutex.

1. `ThreadSafepointState::handle_polling_page_exception()` called from `TestLoop.main`. This means, a thread has been stopped at a safepoint requested by another thread. To investigate a reason of a safepoint, add `-Xlog:safepoint*` JVM option.

```
[75.889s][info][safepoint        ] Application time: 74.0071000 seconds
[75.889s][info][safepoint        ] Entering safepoint region: Cleanup
[75.889s][info][safepoint,cleanup] deflating idle monitors, 0.0000003 secs
[75.889s][info][safepoint,cleanup] updating inline caches, 0.0000058 secs
[75.890s][info][safepoint,cleanup] compilation policy safepoint handler, 0.0000004 secs
[75.890s][info][safepoint,cleanup] purging class loader data graph, 0.0000001 secs
[75.890s][info][safepoint,cleanup] resizing system dictionaries, 0.0000009 secs
[75.890s][info][safepoint,cleanup] safepoint cleanup tasks, 0.0001440 secs
[75.890s][info][safepoint        ] Leaving safepoint region
```

Right, a Cleanup safepoint happens shortly after 74 seconds (exactly the specified delay).
The purpose of a [Cleanup safepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55405726/3448419) is to run periodic tasks; in this case - to update inline caches. If there is cleanup work to do, a safepoint may happen every `GuaranteedSafepointInterval` milliseconds (1000 by default). You can disable periodic safepoints by setting `-XX:GuaranteedSafepointInterval=0`, but this may have [performance implications](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2015-June/018135.html).

2. `SharedRuntime::handle_wrong_method()` from `TimeUtils.now`. This happens when a call site in the compiled code has been made non-entrant. As this is related to JIT compilation, add `-XX:+PrintCompilation` option.

```
  75032 1430 %     4       main.TestLoop::main @ 149 (245 bytes)   made not entrant
  75033 1433 %     3       main.TestLoop::main @ 149 (245 bytes)
  75033 1434       4       util.RealtimeNanoClock::nanoTime (8 bytes)
  75034 1431       3       util.RealtimeNanoClock::nanoTime (8 bytes)   made not entrant
  75039 1435 %     4       main.TestLoop::main @ 149 (245 bytes)
  75043 1433 %     3       main.TestLoop::main @ 149 (245 bytes)   made not entrant
```

Yes, both `TestLoop.main` and `RealtimeNanoClock.nanoTime` were recompiled 75 seconds after JVM start. To find out the reason, add `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation`.

This will produce a large compilation log, where we'll look for an event happened at 75th second.

```
<uncommon_trap thread='173414' reason='unstable_if' action='reinterpret' debug_id='0' compile_id='1232' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c2' level='4' stamp='75.676'>
<jvms bci='161' method='main.TestLoop main ([Ljava/lang/String;)V' bytes='245' count='1' backedge_count='533402' iicount='1'/>
```

That was an [uncommon trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49716888/3448419) due to `unstable_if` at bytecode index 161. In other words, when `main` was JIT compiled, HotSpot did not produce code for the `else` branch, because it was never executed before (such a speculative dead code elimination). However, to retain correctness of the compiled code, HotSpot places a trap to deoptimize and fall back to the interpreter, if the speculative condition fails. This is exactly what happens in your case when `if` condition becomes `false`.

3. `Runtime1::counter_overflow()`. This is again related to recompilation. After running C1 compiled code for some time, HotSpot discovers that the code is hot, and decides to recompile it with C2.

   In this case I caught a contended lock on the compiler queue.

**Conclusion**

HotSpot JIT compilers heavily rely on speculative optimizations. When a speculative condition fails, this leads to deoptimization. Deoptimization is indeed very bad for low latency applications: besides switching to slow execution in the interpreter, this may indirectly cause undesired pauses due to acquiring locks in the JVM runtime, or bringing the JVM to a safepoint.

Common reasons for deoptimization are `unstable_if` and `class_check`. If you want to avoid deoptimization on a latency critical path, make sure to "warm-up" all code paths and all possible receivers for virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! It shows that problem of thread affinity and context switches can not be separated from JVM warmup problem. What about the overhead of proposed tools (async-profiler and JVM flags)? (I mean not only effect on context switches, but on performance in general)

Comment: Wow! This answers is really shipilev! *(Sorry, I am being silly, "shipilev" is an adjective I just invented for texts that explain things that have to do with performance and concurrency in a really detailed and clear way, in the same manner as [Aleksey Shipilëv](https://shipilev.net/) does.)*

Comment: @stepan2271 Performance is relative - I don't have a universal answer. Logging flags are mostly harmless, unless logs are written to a slow disk. Async-profiler usually has low overhead and is suitable for production use, but this depends on the number of events and the stack depth. `-i` (profiling interval) is the main switch to choose between detailed profiles and low performance overhead.