# How can I catch JIT's deoptimization events like "unstable_if" with JNI+JVMTI

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

I've realy though about how can I catch JIT's  deoptimization events.
Today, I've read brilliant answer  by Andrei Pangin [When busy-spining java thread is bound to physical core, can context switch happen by the reason that new branch in code is reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392845/when-busy-spining-java-thread-is-bound-to-physical-core-can-context-switch-happ/64404504#64404504) and thought about it again.

I want to catch JIT's  deoptimization events like "unstable_if, class_check and etc"  with JNI+JVMTI then send alert to my monitoring system or anything else.

Is it possible?
What is it impact on performance JVM ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would suspect that if you could do that, it would impact performance quite measurably, as that's a fairly low-level internal event that also doesn't necessarily indicate any kind of problem (i.e. if you used it as as a problem signal, you'd get many false positives).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncommon traps and deoptimization are HotSpot implementation details. You won't find them in a *standard* interface like JVM TI (which is designed for a generic virtual machine, not just HotSpot).

As suggested in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404504/3448419), one possible way to diagnose deoptimization is to add `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation` options and to look for `<uncommon_trap>` in the compilation log.

Another approach is to trace deoptimization events with [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/).
To do so, use `-e Deoptimization::uncommon_trap_inner`.
This will show you the places in Java code where deoptimization happens, and also timestamps, if using `jfr` output format.

[image: Deoptimization: async-profiler]

Since JDK 14, deoptimization events are also reported natively by Flight Recorder ([JDK-8216041](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216041)). Using Event Browser in JMC, you may find all uncommon traps, including method name, bytecode index, deoptimization reason, etc.

[image: Deoptimization: JFR]

The overhead of all the above approaches is small enough. There is usually no problem in using async-profiler in production; JFR is also fine, if the recording settings are not superfluous.

However, there is no much use in profiling deoptimizations, except for very special cases. This is absolutely normal for a typical Java application to recompile methods multiple times, as long as the JVM learns more about the application in runtime. It may sound weird, but uncommon traps is a common technique of the speculative optimization :) As you can see on the above pictures, even basic methods like `HashMap.put` may cause deoptimization, and this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

From JDK 14 (based on OpenJDK) you can access deoptimization events programmatically using the Event Steaming API. There is no API from native.

```
import jdk.jfr.consumer.RecordingStream;

RecordingStream s = new RecordingStream();
s.enable("jdk.Deoptimization").withStackTrace();
s.onEvent("jdk.Deoptimization", e -> {
  System.out.println("Time: " + e.getEndTime());
  System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getString("reason"));
  System.out.println("Action: " + e.getString("action"));
  System.out.println("Instruction: "+ e.getString("instruction"));
  System.out.println("Line Number: " + e.getInt("lineNumber"));
  System.out.println("Bytecode Index" + e.getInt("bci"));
  RecordedMethod m = e.getValue("method");
  RecordedStackTrace st = e.getStackTrace();
  RecordedThread t = e.getThread();
  ...
});
s.start();
```